# Add class for css in ejs by node

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

Please mind the environment of this Application. I'm using

1. Windows
2. NPM ,Express
3. MySQL

This is the code in ejs template. example.ejs

```
<% if (message) { %>
                <p class="alert " id="errorMessage">
                    <%= message %>
                </p>
            <% } %>
```

I want to add class to p.

This is what I am doing but didn't work.

```
messages = "Password Successfully Changed";
jQuery('#errorMessage').addClass('successMessage');
res.render('profile',{page_title:"My Profile",data:rows,message: messages});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
var messageData = {
  message : "Password Successfully Changed",
  class : "successMessage"
};
res.render('profile',{page_title:"My Profile",data:rows,message: messageData });
```

then on template side.

```
<% if (globalMessage) { %>
    <p class="alert <%= globalMessage.class %>" id="errorMessage">
       <%= globalMessage.message %>
    </p>
<% } %>
```